# Eclipse to Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

For my school project I made a game on eclipse. To load in sprites and other images I used:

```
BufferedImage spritesheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Sprites/Enemies/enemyA.gif"));
```

Despite my code not having any errors it runs but is all black and wont let me use any of my controls set previously. Does anyone know a certain format or way that i can work my game in netbeans.

Noted errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
    at TileMap.Background.<init>(Background.java:24)
    at GameState.MenuState.<init>(MenuState.java:28)
    at GameState.GameStateManager.loadState(GameStateManager.java:26)
    at GameState.GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:20)
    at Main.GamePanel.init(GamePanel.java:55)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 35 seconds)
```

Comment: The resources need to be stored within the `src` directory

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention my teacher is making me transfer it to netbeans. I imported the project the way i was suppose to but it doesn't work HELP pls :D <3

Comment: How do i do that MadProgrammer

Comment: Why is your teacher enforcing IDEs

Comment: `/Sprites/Enemies/enemyA.gif` needs to be copied into the netbean's projects `src` directory